# Symfony listener start after Twig extensions on first launch

Tags: php, symfony, service, listener, twig-extension

Here is my service.yml :

```
services:
foo.builder:
    class: MyBundle\Core\MyClass

foo.twig_extension:
    class: MyBundle\Twig\BarExtension
    arguments: ['@foo.builder']
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }

foo.listener.foolistener:
  class: MyBundle\EventListener\MyListener
  arguments: ['@service_container']
  tags:
    -  { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: createFooObject }
```

My listener always start before my twig extensions and it's good, but not just after clear the cache...
My app is always crashing the first time (after clearing the cache or change the parameters) because my twig extension needs to have an object already hydrated by the listener. So if it start before, it normally crash :(

1/ what is the problem ?

2/ how can i force my listener to start always before twig extension ?

Any suggestions will be welcome

Comment: You can't.  Twig extensions will always be created before the listeners get called.  What you need to do is to get your object when the twig filter or function is called.

Comment: But...Just the first time after clearing the cache ???

Comment: You are misinterpreting your conclusion about cache clearing.  I am assuming that the results of MyListener::createFooObject  ends up in your extension?  Perhaps post a bit more code and maybe we can see exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

[Event listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-listener) page reads:

> The other optional tag attribute is called `priority`, which defaults to **0** and it controls the order in which listeners are executed (*the highest the priority, the earlier a listener is executed*). This is useful when you need to guarantee that one listener is executed before another. The priorities of the internal Symfony listeners usually range from `-255` to `255` but your own listeners can use any positive or negative integer.

List your listeners and their priorities with command:

```
php app(or bin)/console debug:event-dispatcher
```

and assign appropriate `priority` to it like below. Update `priority: 0`. If you don't set it at all, the priority value defaults to `0`.

```
- { name: kernel.whatever, event: kernel.whatever, method: whatever, priority: 0 }
```

Comment: Problem of course is that twig extensions are not listeners.